# What controls whether $P\left(X=1 \mid Z, W\right) - P\left(X=1 \mid W\right)$ is positive or negative? Is it dependent on $cor(X, Z)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose we have a binary random variable $X$ and two other random variables $W,Z$. I am interested in the two conditional probabilities $P\left(X=1 \mid Z, W\right)$ and $P\left(X=1 \mid W\right)$, and the relationship between them. For example, if $X \perp Z \mid W$, we have that

\begin{align}
P\left(X=1 \mid Z, W\right) - P\left(X=1 \mid W\right) &= P\left(X=1 \mid W\right) - P\left(X=1 \mid W\right) \\
&= 0
\end{align}

However, generally what controls this difference? In other words, when should I expect $P\left(X=1 \mid Z, W\right)$ to be less than or greater than $P\left(X=1 \mid W\right)$?

By the conditional independence above, it ***seems*** to indicate to me its the level of correlation between $X$ and $Z$ and the direction of this correlation (negative/positive). Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the events here are $W$, $Z$ and the random variable $X=1$

Then you can say the sign of $P(X=1 \mid Z,W)-P(X=1 \mid W)$ indicates that, given $W$, the event $X=1$ is positively, negatively, or not conditionally correlated with the event $Z$, and that if they are not conditionally correlated then they are conditionally independent.

Comment: Does it depend how $Z$ relates to $X$ and $W$? Or does this hold under any $Z$?

Comment: Did you mean "conditionally correlated with the event $Z$" instead of "conditionally correlated with the event $W$" above?

Comment: @user321627 - on your first comment, this can be derived from a definition of correlation.  Your second comment is correct - thank you